# Python 3: How to call function from another file and pass arguments to that function ?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I want to call a function from another file and pass arguments from current file to that file. With below example, In file **bye.py** I want to call function "**me**" from "**hi.py**" file and pass "**goodbye**" string to function "**me**". How to do that ? Thank you :)

I have file hi.py

```
def me(string):
    print(string)
me('hello')
```

bye.py

```
from hi import me
me('goodbye')
```

What I got:

```
hello
goodbye
```

What I would like:

```
goodbye
```

Comment: Remove `me('hello')`  from hi.py?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when you create files to be imported you must use `if __name__ == '__main__'` which evaluates to false in case you are importing the file from another file. So your hi.py may look as:

```
def me(string):
    print(string)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Do some local work which should not be reflected while importing this file to another module.
    me('hello')
```